# Dart: pub build not working, while serve works

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am trying to build my WebGL dart application with "pub build".
I am able to run "pub serve" without problems, but "pub build" gives me 2 erros:

```
Directive not allowed here
part of MyProject
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Could not find main [I think this happends because of unfinished compile]
```

I only use browser:any as dependency.
Why could this be?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
My pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: LD29
description: My LD29 game
author: snip
homepage: snip
dependencies:
    browser: any
```

The includes:

```dart
library LD29;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:web_gl';

part 'Scene.dart';
part 'MainScene.dart';
part 'Entities.dart';

part 'Quadgrid.dart';
part 'Vecd.dart';
part 'Quad.dart';
part 'TexQuad.dart';
part 'ShaderProgram.dart';
part 'ShaderSource.dart';
part 'TextureGL.dart';
part 'FontRendering.dart';
```

The problematic "part of"

```dart
part of LD29;

class Quadgrid {

  const static int size = 20;
  const MAX_GRID_W = DISPLAY_WIDTH / size;
  const MAX_GRID_H = DISPLAY_HEIGHT / size;

  ...
}
```

It seems no diffrent from my other files.

Comment: There is not enough information to help. Can you please provide at least the code around "here"? Why do you think this has to do with `yaml`?

Comment: Because I think it is really odd that I can pub serve but not pub build. Included more info!

Comment: And can you successfully open the web page in Chrome or Firefox (not Dartium) when you run `pub serve`?

Comment: Yes, my WebGL application runs without problems in Chromium with "pub serve".
EDIT: Even a dircet call to dart2js works!

Comment: Can you make your project available on GitHub so I can take a look. I think the information you provided is not sufficient to find the cause.

Comment: Can you try to make your library and package name different?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I seem to be facing the same problem with my app and haven't been able to sort it. https://github.com/ChildrenOfUr/coUclient if it helps anyone diagnose.

Comment: No I did not. I just ditched the pub build process and invoked dart2js manually. That did work.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after coming back to it a few months later, I gave debugging this problem another go. For my application, we moved the main() method to a different file than the one that had the 'library coUclient' command at the top. This meant that 'pub build' would fail:

```
master@dellaptop ~/Dropbox/Dart/coUclient $ pub build
Loading source assets... 
Building coUclient... 
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling coUclient|web/dart/engine/initialize.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/dart/engine/initialize.dart:1:1:
Directive not allowed here.
part of coUclient;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/dart/engine/initialize.dart:11:5:
Cannot resolve 'localStorage'.
        if(localStorage["interface"] == null || localStorage["interface"] == "desktop")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't know why I didn't see it before, but what tipped me off was that I saw it was starting the compile with initalize.dart and it occurred to me that that was the file that had main() in it. I then moved the main() method back into main.dart (which has the 'library coUclient' command at the top) and re-ran pub build. This time it succeeded because it started:

```
Loading source assets... 
Building coUclient... 
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling coUclient|web/main.dart...
[Dart2JS on coUclient|web/main.dart]:
```

and all went well.

Moral of the story is, make sure your main() is in the same file as your 'library ' command and the "Directive not allowed here" problem shouldn't happen.